# Source Code fir Tiles struts-tiles2-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: struts, tiles, tiles2, struts-1

I am not able to find the source code of struts-tiles2-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar version of tiles.
The jar files are present at http://people.apache.org/~pbenedict/struts-osgi/org/apache/struts/struts-tiles2/1.4.0-SNAPSHOT/ location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While choosing a **Struts2 Tiles** plugin, you must ensure it is the one designed for your version of Tiles (`2` or `3`), and it is the exact version of your Struts2 JAR (`2.3.16`, for example)

List for Tiles 2:

- [Struts 2 **Tiles 2** Plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-tiles-plugin)

List for Tiles 3:

- [Struts 2 **Tiles 3** Plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-tiles3-plugin)

  - (related : [How to integrate Struts2 with Tiles 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337938/how-to-integrate-struts-2-with-tiles-3))
  - (related : [Tiles 3 not Rendering List attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14540358/1654265))

The version `1.4.0` in your question it's not a valid Struts2 version, since Struts2 starts from `2.0.x`, it is a Struts1 version: [**Struts1 Tiles2** plugin](http://feima2011.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/struts-1-and-tiles-2-integration/) (the <kbd>Struts2</kbd> tag in the question was misleading).

> You can find [the source code here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/struts1/trunk/tiles2/).

Please remember that [Struts1 is EOL](https://struts.apache.org/struts1eol-announcement.html).